# Cakephp change model's title without rename model/dbtable

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I have a table that store all information about class, but because Class is reserved for class name I had to rename the table from classes to types.

But in the view section I need it to be displayed as "Class", including the Paginator links.

Anyway to achieve this by adding something in the Type model, without completely customize Paginator and and all view compoenents?

Answer (score 1):

Which display elements in the view are you trying to customise?

As you could probably do this using routes.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/341/Routes